# Field of polynomials mod n?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

I have a few questions and i am looking for some clarification.

1) Is it correct that one can define a field $(Z_n, +, X)$ of integers mod $n$, where all the elements are integers $a$ such that $gcd(a, n)$ = $1$? In other words, this can be a field even when $n$ is not prime, just so long as we delete some elements? Van anyone tell me if this partiular field (if it is a field) has a name?

2) If we call the field above $F$, then is $F(x)$ a field? So the only factors of polynomials are either quadratics (with complex roots over $C{(x)}$) or linear factors of the form $x-a$ for $a \in F$?

Comment: This is all wrong. For part 1, there is no field built of invertible numbers mod $n$ when $n$ is not prime. If you want to construct finite fields of non-prime size you must move beyond constructions like ${\mathbf Z}/(n)$. The second part doesn't make any sense either since your notation $F\{x\}$ is non-standard: what does it mean? And speaking about complex roots of polynomials with coefficients in a finite field is mixing apples and oranges (at the level at which this question is written). If you gave some background to your question it might help clear up what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: If you only look at integers mod $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$, you do not have a set that is closed under addition.

Answer (score 1):

About (1), as KCd says it's pretty easy to show that no such field can exist (although you can make a perfectly good group this way).

For example suppose you had some set $S \subset Z / nZ$ with addition and multiplication modulo $n$.  Let $\overline{m}$ be the multiplicative identity, ie $\overline{m}\overline{x} = \overline{x}$ for all $\overline{x} \in S$.  Then letting $x \in Z$ be any representative of $\overline{x}$ we have that $\overline{m} + \overline{m} + ... + \overline{m}$ ($x$ times) equals $\overline{x}$.  So $\overline{m}$ generates $S$, and every representative of $S$ is a multiple of $m$.  Note that the set of equivalence classes is the same then if we changed to modulo $lcm(m,n)$ (since $\overline{x} = \overline{0}$ iff $n \mid x$ which implies $lcm(n,m)$ divides $x$ anyways).  Thus $S = mZ/lcm(n,m)Z = mZ/kmZ$ for some $k$.  And then $mZ/mkZ \simeq Z/kZ$ implying $k$ must be a prime, otherwise we have zero divisors.